# How to feed array elements from user (i.e., the console) and how to pass array elements to a function as arguments

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

Here is the original code of Visual C++ which I have been trying to manipulate for more than a day. 
This is the simplest error-free program which runs correctly.
What I want to do is insert two functions:  one for taking input from a user, and another for displaying output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int i, j,r,c;
    int arr[5][5];
    cout<< "enter r and c";
    cin>> i>> j;

    for(r=1;r<=i;r++)
    {
        for(c=1;c<=j;c++)
        {
            cout<< "enter elements";
            cin>> arr[r][c];
        }
    }

    cout<< " elements are"<< endl;
    for(r=1;r<=i;r++)
    {
        for(c=1;c<=j;c++)
        {

            cout<<setw(4) <<arr[r][c];
        }
        cout<< endl<< endl;
    }

    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
}
```

This is what I tried doing but it's giving errors.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int input(int i, int j, int arr)
{   
    int r,c;
    for(r=1;r<=i;r++)
    {
        for(c=1;c<=j;c++)
        {
            cout<< "enter elements";
            cin>> arr[r][c];

        }
    }
    return arr[r][c];
}
void output(int i, int j, int arr)
{   
    int r,c;
    for(r=1;r<=i;r++)
    {
        for(c=1;c<=j;c++)
        {

            cout<<setw(4) <<arr[r][c];
        }
        cout<< endl<< endl;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int i, j,r,c;
    int arr[5][5];
    cout<< "enter r and c";
    cin>> i>> j;

    input(i,j,arr);

    cout<< " elements are"<< endl;

    output(i,j,arr);
    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I think you have some learning to do. You are passing an array as an integer, then trying to modify the integer as if it were an array.  int input(int i, int j, int arr) <-- "int arr" does not take an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need a deeper understanding of C++, pointers, and functions. The following is what you are looking for (of sort), however, you certainly need a much deeper understanding of C++:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void output(int ** array)
{
    for (int i= 0;i<5;++i)
    {
        for (int a= 0;a<5;++a)
        {
            cout << "Array[" << i << "][" << a << "] = " << array[a][i] << endl;
        }
    }
}

void input(int ** array)
{
    for (int i= 0;i<5;++i)
    {
        for (int a= 0;a<5;++a)
        {
            cout << "Array[" << i << "][" << a << "] = " << endl;
            cin >> array[i][a];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int** array;
    array = new int*[5];
    for (int i=0;i<5;++i)
        array[i] = new int[5];
    input(array);
    output (array);
    delete []array;
    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, explaining this would be like teaching you C++ from scratch. Whatever method you are using to learn C++, stick with it. You will get there, you're just not quite ready. One thing you will find is it's not always easy to take things to the next level. There is a reason things go and stop where they do when learning. Though, taking that extra step, or attempting to, isn't bad, you just need to know when it isn't time, yet.

Edit:

For the sake of completion, here is an example with no pointers:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void output(int array[5][5])
{
    for (int i= 0;i<5;++i)
    {
        for (int a= 0;a<5;++a)
        {
            cout << "Array[" << i << "][" << a << "] = " << array[a][i] << endl;
        }
    }
}

void input(int array[5][5])
{
    for (int i= 0;i<5;++i)
    {
        for (int a= 0;a<5;++a)
        {
            array[i][a] = i*a;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[5][5];
    input(array);
    output (array);
    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking all the pains. now, just one more thing, which i was trying to do is insert the value of row and column from the user. is it possible ?

Comment: Look at the first example using pointers, it works just the same: cin >> array[i][a];

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from your input function you're returning a value in a loop which makes the loop stop and return to the main function.

So, if you want to `cin` a dimension of the input matrix, you should change the return type of the input function to void, and remove the return `arr[r][c];`.

Secondly, you defined `arr[5][5]` in the main loop which isn't accessible from the other function, and you are not even passing a pointer variable. You should pass a double pointer to the input function in order to do that, or you can just define the `arr[5][5]` outside of the main function.

Lastly, you are assigning a size of the matrix but you are not dynamically assigning its size.

I suggest that a little more understanding of functions and variables in C/C++ is in order.

Answer (score 0):

As every body has pointed you need to strengthen your programming basics.

1. First the return type of main should be **int**. Remember this.
2. signature of input should be something like this `void input(int i, int j, int arr[][5])`
3. same goes for `output`
4. Also while iterating to read/write in a array the offset starts from 0 not 1, and ends at `SIZE - 1`. So change 
   `for(r=1;r<=i;r++)` to `for(r=0;r<i;r++)`
5. arrays are always passed by reference, so the changes inside function will be reflected inside calling function, so you don't need to return the array.

Answer (score 0):

Why the input and out order differ...is it typo?

void output(int array[5][5])

```
cout << "Array[" << i << "][" << a << "] = " << array[a][i] << endl; // typo may be
cout << "Array[" << i << "][" << a << "] = " << array[i][a] << endl; // correction
```

Comment: This should be a comment.