# Infinite objects

Tags: c++, object

I have a program the has an array of objects called convict made up of the class Inmate.
The code looks like this:

```
int intakeAmount;
cout << "How many inmates came in today";
cin >> intakeAmount;
Inmate convict[intakeAmount];
```

As you can see the user has to enter exactly how many inmates are coming in to the system. It later ask the user to input information for each convict that was created. This works well, but what if the user doesn't know how many convicts are coming in to the system that day? How can I make it to were a new convict is created whenever the user needs to create one and still be able to access each convicts attributes (i.e. name, sex, age, height, and weight)? I already have my class set up and getters and setters in place. This is for my own personal knowledge and has nothing to do with any kind of homework or test.

Other examples:
Minecraft - I know this is java and I admit I have never played it, but I do know the world is unlimited and the user can create an infinite amount of objects.

Another old school example of something I have played is:
Roller Coaster Tycon - You could create as many gardeners and mechanics as you wanted to.

Comment: This isn't actually valid C++ since array sizes need to be known at compile time. You want `std::vector`.

Comment: Sounds like you need at least a menu driven cmd app which loops back around to the choices of `1) Add convict 2) Access convict etc.` Or use a GUI. Then you just access the element based on the user's desired property, i.e.; name, number, etc.. As far as not knowing the amount you could use a `list`, `vector`, or some other similar structure.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a linked list? It's a good exercise, something every programer should learn.

Comment: Arrays can be used as implicit linked lists where every item is adjacent in memory, rather than chase pointers.  Faster to scan and if you're not sorting them and just push back at the end then addition is at least as fast as a linked list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to dynamically allocate arrays, as suggested std::vector will automatically resize when it needs to so use that.

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

vector<bool> numbers( N);
```

If you avoid new & delete, but declare a vector you'll find it's `sizeof` doesn't include the actual vector.  So it's not allocating large amount of memory on stack, and will atomatically free the memory, when it goes out of scope, using RAII which avoids memory leaks much more reliabily than the subtleties of allocating yourself with new/delete.

[C++ Information pages for std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector)

[Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Comment: Sorry to the 'user' log in who suggested edit, my post got pushed up accidentally and I was adding to it, so your correct suggestion got rejected before I could merge or accept it

Comment: The big picture (and the reason this is a good answer) is that you should look for the data structure implementations that are designed to do the things you need easily, rather than try to figure out how to use a hard-to-use implementation (arrays, in this case) for the task.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally I had to drop out during data strutters in java. Just started back programming. Thanks for the link as well.

Comment: From Java, the RAII idea is vital reading; otherwise you'll end up doing new/delete bookkeeping (badly) and complaing about lack of garbage collection, when simply declaring class objects as variables allowing their con/de-structor pairs to do the work as they come in & out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want to add a new column vector for the new inmate. C++ will give you a hard time trying to input an array from the terminal.

I found the follow answer allows you to modify an array from the terminal.
1:[[How to feed array elements from user (i.e., the console) and how to pass array elements to a function as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707893/how-to-feed-array-elements-from-user-i-e-the-console-and-how-to-pass-array-e])

It then outputs every value that you entered for each vector.